# Epsilon transition in NFA to DFA conversion

Tags: computer-science, self-learning, automata

[image]

[image]

I worked through this conversion and it all makes sense except for one small part. Shouldn't $(q_1q_2)$ go to $q_1$ in the DFA on input $0$, not a self loop?

We have state $q_iq_2$ to begin with because $q_0$ goes to $q_1$ and $q_2$ on a $1$.

Then trying to figure out what states $(q_1q_2)$ goes to:

On a $0$ $(q_1q_2)$ goes to $q_1$ because in the original NFA $q_1$ goes to $q_1$ and $q_2$ goes to the empty set. 
On a $1$ $(q_1q_2)$ goes to $q_3$ because in the original NFA $q_1$ goes to $q_3$ and $q_2$ goes to the $q_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the technique is: for each transition $q \to^a Q'$ of the NFA (NFA transitions are from states to sets of states), you take $$q \to^a \text{state}\big(Q'\cup\{q'' ~|~q'\in Q'~\text{and}~q'\to^\epsilon Q''~\text{and}~q''\in Q''\}\big)$$

This is just a formal way to say "in $q\to^a Q'$, take into account also the $\epsilon$-transitions from $Q'$".

Here, it's $q_1 \to^0\{q_1\}$. Therefore, this results to $q_1 \to^0 \text{state}\big(\{q_1\}\cup\{q_2\}\big) = (q_1, q_2)$.

The function "state" is just to map a set of states of the initial NFA to the corresponding state of the DFA.

Comment: I was told by my professor that after the input is consumed, the state stops. That is, once the input 0 is consumed it cannot move further even if there are epsilon transitions. (I also updated the question to make it more specific)

Comment: It sounded like my professor meant you can consume them before the input is accepted but not after. However doesnt this contradict with what the textbook shows.

Comment: @JacFrall Indeed it contradicts the pictures, so at this point I'm not sure what your professor meant. Note that the same happens with transition $q_3 \to^1 q_4$.

Comment: Is this from Sipser's book? If yes, then indeed $\epsilon$-transitions are taken into account in the end. You're missing that extra step ($E(R)$, where $R\subseteq Q$). That's the final transition function.

Comment: No this is a book written by my professor

Comment: Ok, then he should take the $\epsilon$-transition into account at some point. If not right before or right after character consumption, then one should re-iterate over the NFA's transition function and update the DFA's transitions accordingly (counting only the $\epsilon$-transitions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92967/discussion-between-jac-frall-and-frabala).